# Trying to disable the touchpad at wakeup

Tags: suspend, touchpad, xinput, trackpoint

I am using a Thinkpad L13 Yoga and had the problem that the trackpoint stopped working after wakeup. So I followed the following hint (which basically reloads the psmouse module at wakeup): https://askubuntu.com/a/1159960/270792

After putting the file in place the trackpoint stopped failing at wakeup, however, the touchpad now was activated. I would like, however, to keep the touchpad deactivated since I sometimes touch it with my palms unintentionally.

So i tried to disable the touchpad at wakeup. Here is how my `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/trackpoint-fix` script currently looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0` if no pre suspend action required
    modprobe -r psmouse
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` if no post suspend action required
    sleep 2
    echo "Will now modprobe psmouse..."
    modprobe psmouse
    sleep 2
    echo "Will now disable the touchpad..."
    DISPLAY=:0 xinput disable 'Elan Touchpad'
    sleep 2
    echo "Will now show touchpad state..."
    DISPLAY=:0 xinput list-props 'Elan Touchpad' | grep 'Device Enabled'
    ;;
esac
```

This is what I find in my logs:

```
Mai 24 15:13:42 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[2919]: Going to suspend...
Mai 24 15:13:42 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[2916]: Suspending system...
Mai 24 15:13:50 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[2916]: System resumed.
Mai 24 15:13:50 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[3073]: Waking up from suspend...
Mai 24 15:13:52 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[3073]: Will now modprobe psmouse...
Mai 24 15:13:54 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[3073]: Will now disable the touchpad...
Mai 24 15:13:56 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[3073]: Will now show touchpad state...
Mai 24 15:13:56 ThinkpadL13Yoga systemd-sleep[3326]:         Device Enabled (184):        0
```

So, looking at the last line, it seems like the touchpad device has been disabled successfully. However, the touchpad is still active. If I check the state of the touchpad inside the X session after wakeup, it tells me that the device is indeed enabled:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 xinput list-props 'Elan Touchpad' | grep 'Device Enabled'
    Device Enabled (184):   1
```

I absolutely don't understand how the touchpad gets enabled again and would like to keep it disabled. Possibly, reloading psmouse isn't a suiting solution and there is a better approach to keep the trackpoint enabled after wakeup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could solve my problem by following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1354447/270792

It actually solved two issues:

1. The touchpad is now reliably disabled after suspend
2. The scrolling with the middle mouse key is now functional after suspend

Comment: Please comment on your downvote. Is posting a link to a working solution as answer considered bad practice? If so, how should I handle it instead?